# 403 forbidden message in Visual Studio 2013 connecting to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm working on a project for a client who has their own TFS server. All of the other devs on my team are able to connect to and login to this server via a browser and Visual Studio.

I can access via a browser, but when I go to *Add Server* in Visual Studio, I never get asked for credentials. I only get the below 403 Forbidden dialog. I've deleted the VS cache folder, I've removed all of my previous servers, I've also removed any TFS related credentials in the Account Manager and I still get this dialog.

All of us on the team have the same configurations on our machines...Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

[image]

Very strange that I'm not prompted at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: What URI are you entering?

Comment: The exact same one my other teammates are using: https://tfs.ourclientserver.com:8181/tfs
Our client did have us manually install a cert for that domain, which I've done.

Comment: Are you able to connect to TFS with your credential on your team member's machine?

Answer (score 0):

Contact your client to see whether their server has IP restrictions.